# Limiting items from a query through href for Pagination

Tags: php, sql

I have to display different items from a SQL database, up to 8 per page using and be able to sort using MVC design philosophy without hard coding different pages within my Controller path. I'm having issues understanding, how exactly to reference the two properties necessary and how to limit.

We're connecting to a MySQL via Xampp. Within my Controller Path index file I assign an $action to view the first sample of data. I then display the list of categories and products with pagination being required at the bottom. My professor suggested finding out the page number, filtering it, then using it within the LIMIT, he even gave me a code snippit. Whenever I try to use that LIMIT to the query nothing show up even though I've read that $variables can be recognized in LIMIT and I'm not understanding how to reference both `page_number` and `category_id` in my index to prevent having to create multiple query functions within my Model path without hard coding seperate pages and functions. Help would be greatly appreciated.

This is the function within the Model Path

```
function get_products_by_category($category_id, $pn) 
{
    global $db;

    $arithmetic = 8*($pn -1);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM products 
              WHERE products.categoryID = :category_id
              ORDER BY productID LIMIT $arithmetic, 8";
    $statement = $db->prepare($query);
    $statement->bindValue(":category_id", $category_id);
    $statement->execute();
    $products = $statement->fetchAll();
    $statement->closeCursor();
    return $products;
}
```

This is the index page within the Controller path

```
$pn = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'page_number', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
    if ($pn == NULL || $pn == FALSE) 
    {
            $pn = 1;

    }

$action = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'action');
if ($action == NULL) 
{
    $action = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'action');
    if ($action == NULL) 
    {
        $action = 'list_products';
    }
}

if ($action == 'list_products') 
{
    $category_id = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'category_id', 
            FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
    if ($category_id == NULL || $category_id == FALSE) 
    {
            $category_id = 1;

    }

    $category_name = get_category_name($category_id);
    $categories = get_categories();
    $products = get_products_by_category($category_id, $pn);
    $total = count($products);
    include('product_list.php');  

}
```

This is the display page within the controller path

```
<?php 
    $pn;
    $current_category;
    $total_page = $total/8; 
    $remain = $total % 8;
    if($remain > 0)
    {
        $total_page = $total_page + 1;
    }
    ?>


    <aside>
        <!-- display a list of categories -->
        <h2>Categories</h2>
        <nav>
        <ul>    
        <?php foreach ($categories as $category) : ?>
            <li>
                <a href="?category_id=<?php echo $category['categoryID']; ?>">
                <?php echo $category['categoryName'];?>
                </a>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>


    <section>

<?php   
        for($i = 1; $i <= $total_page; $i++)
        {
        ?>
            <a href="?page_number= <?php echo $i; ?> & ?category_id= <?php echo $category['categoryID']; ?>
                "><?php echo $i; ?> </a> &nbsp;
        <?php
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: Your query in get_products_by_category function should be in double quote (") not single quotes (') because it is now not evaluating $pn variable.

Comment: Is that for all arithmetic in general or just for $variables?